# Store returned errors (or messages) of MATLAB as cell array

Tags: matlab, user-interface, error-handling, try-catch, matlab-guide

Suppose that running m-file in MATLAB R2015a returns 5 errors. I want store these errors (or messages) separately in a cell array. for example `c{1}` is first error, `c{2}` is second error, etc. I can't use `try-catch` structure because m-files are nested (I didn't create these m-files) and i can't find origin of an error. I want only return error(s) in my created GUI dialogs based on these m-files.

Sample error:

```
Error using i_a (line 102)
IDETooManyParams

Error in i_a (line 280)
    [idehess_point, idemoments_point, idemodel_point, idelre_point, derivatives_info_point,
    info] = ...

Error in ex5 (line 188)
i_a(options_ident);

Error in xx(line 180)
evalin('base',fname) ;
```

I want have `IDETooManyParams` as a string (or possibly other errors).

Comment: how can there be more than 1 error? do you mean you want to get the error message and the stack trace where the error occured?

Comment: I want store these outputs as strings in a call array. these is combination of errors, warnings and messages in command prompt of MATLAB.after running main m-file.

Comment: There can be a combination of warnings, but not of errors. There is just 1 error and its stacktrace. you can get the whole stacktrace by `getReport(exception,'extended')`

Comment: @Ander Biguri `getReport(MException,'extended')` returns `Not enough input arguments.`.

Comment: I add some information in the question.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use a try-catch block.

Comment: @excaza Because I'm creating GUI for a toolbox with more than 1000 m-files with a main m-file that I'm running. Totally there are more than 400 predefined errors and warnings in these nested files. So i only want store errors in command prompt of MATLAB and returm there errors in my GUI.

Comment: If you have a block of error handling logic then there should already be a place to catch, log, and rethrow errors that are not explicitly handled.

Comment: @excaza There is another problem that my main file is a `.mod` file. MATLAB translate this file to a `m-file` automatically. So i can't directly add `try-catch` block in `m-file`.

Comment: There is a lot of information in the comments that would have been good to include in your question. Regardless, if your desire is to do this programmatically there needs to be a catch _somewhere_ to log the error structure. Either you add this to the existing code base, create a wrapper function with a try-catch block, or maybe a button in your GUI to pull the error using `lasterror`, as suggested below?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last error message and the stacktrace through [`lasterror`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lasterror.html).